# Global __syncthreads() after initializing global memory variable

Tags: cuda

I have a CUDA kernel that starts with setting a global counter to zero, does some calculations, increments a shared counter and then adds the shared counters of different blocks to the global counter. Now I want to make sure, that the initialization happens before any incrementation of the global counter. Here is a simplified example of my kernel:

```
__global__ void counter_function(int32_t* global_count, int32_t* other_data)
{
    __shared__ int32_t block_count;
    bool condition = false;

    // first thread of first block initializes global counter
    if (thread.Idx == 0 && block.Idx == 0) {
        *global_count = 0;
    }

    // do some calculation on other_data and possibliy set
    // condition = true;

    // increment counter if condition is true
    if (condition) {
        atomicAdd(&block_count, 1);
    }

    __synchthreads();

    // first thread of each block adds its count to the global count
    if (thread.Idx == 0) {
        atomicAdd(&global_count, block_count);
    }
}
```

I have read through [Memory Fence Functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#memory-fence-functions) and [Synchronization Functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#synchronization-functions) of the CUDA C Programming Guide, but could not find a solution, since `__syncthreads()` only synchronises threads per block and `__threadfence()` only takes care of the order of global read/write operations within threads, as far as I understood. And since all threads, except the one that initializes the global count, have only one global write operation, that doesn't seem to be of any use in my case either. Am I understanding the `__threadfence()` function right?

One way seems to be to split the kernel into two kernels, so basically having a seperate kernel that only sets the counter to zero. But is there a better way?

Any suggestions how to solve this? Or am I missing something?

Comment: "// first thread of first block initializes global counter" there's no guarantee (in CUDA) that the first thread of the first block will execute first.  In a large grid, it's possible that the first block does not begin executing until other blocks *have completed*.   And there are no global sync mechanisms in CUDA, other than the kernel launch.  So initialize `global_count` on the host, before launching the kernel.  Could be done trivially with a `cudaMemset(global_count, 0, sizeof(int32_t));` before the kernel.  Is that the extent of your question?

Comment: Yes, that is the extent of my question. Thanks. It seems in my case to be better then invoking an extra kernel as the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404992/cuda-block-synchronization\ suggests.

Answer (score 0):

In CUDA there is no function that allows you to "synchthreads" between the blocks. Also, as @Robert Crovella already mentioned, threads execution order is unspecified. You should write 2 separate kernels and call cudaDeviceSynchronize after execution of the former to be sure that the requested operation has been executed.

Moreover, atomicAdd in your code seems to be unnecessary. It is better to have a vector of int where each thread can update one separate element and then perform Reduce operation on the whole vector.

Comment: There is no reason to use `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` in between two kernels issued to the same stream.  The CUDA stream semantics guarantee that the second kernel will not begin executing until the first kernel is complete.

Comment: What I haven't included in my code is, that each thread also writes its threadID to a vector in global memory and for compatibility for later kernels that vector needs to IDs to be in the first entries (and not interrupted by entries where the thread didn't pass `condition`.). And the location of the array is determined by the return value of the `atomicAdd` at the moment. But I came across `thrust::copy_if` which could solve that problem and help avoiding `atomicAdd` at all. I'm gonna check if that's faster. Thanks for the hint.