# The way to properly do multiple CUDA block synchronization

Tags: cuda, synchronization, block

I like to do CUDA synchronization for multiple blocks. It is not for each block where __syncthreads() can easily handle it.

I saw there are exiting discussions on this topic, for example [cuda block synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404992/cuda-block-synchronization), and I like the simple solution brought up by @johan, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67252761/3188690, essentially it uses a 64 bits counter to track the synchronized blocks.

However, I wrote the following code trying to accomplish the similar job but meet a problem. Here I used the term `environment` so that the `wkNumberEnvs` of blocks within this environment shall be synchronized. It has a counter. I used `atomicAdd()` to count how many blocks have already been synchronized themselves, once the number of sync blocks == `wkBlocksPerEnv`, I know all blocks finished sync and it is free to go. However, it has a strange outcome that I am not sure why.

The problem comes from this while loop. Since the first threads of all blocks are doing the atomicAdd, there is a while loop to check until the condition meets. But I find that some blocks will be stuck into the endless loop, which I am not sure why the condition cannot be met eventually? And if I printf some messages either in `*** I can print here 1` or `*** I can print here 2`, there is no endless loop and everything is perfect. I do not see something obvious.

```
const int wkBlocksPerEnv = 2;

__device__ int env_sync_block_count[wkNumberEnvs];

__device__ void syncthreads_for_env(){
    // sync threads for each block so all threads in this block finished the previous tasks
    __syncthreads();

    // sync threads for wkBlocksPerEnv blocks for each environment
    if(wkBlocksPerEnv > 1){
       const int kThisEnvId = get_env_scope_block_id(blockIdx.x);

       if (threadIdx.x == 0){
            // incrementing env_sync_block_count by 1
            atomicAdd(&env_sync_block_count[kThisEnvId], 1);
            // *** I can print here 1
            while(env_sync_block_count[kThisEnvId] != wkBlocksPerEnv){
            // *** I can print here 2
            }

    // Do the next job ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two potential issues with your code. Caching and block scheduling.

Caching can prevent you from observing an updated value during the while loop.

Block scheduling can cause a dead-lock if you wait for an update of a block which has not yet been scheduled. Since CUDA does not guarantee a specific order of scheduled blocks, the only way to prevent this dead-lock is to limit the number of blocks in the grid such that all blocks can run simultaneously.

Following code shows how you could synchronize multiple blocks while avoiding above issues. I adapted the code from the multi-grid synchronization given in the CUDA-sample `conjugateGradientMultiDeviceCG` https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/4_CUDA_Libraries/conjugateGradientMultiDeviceCG/conjugateGradientMultiDeviceCG.cu#L186

On pre-Volta devices, it uses volatile memory accesses. Volta and later uses acquire/release semantics.
Grid size is limited by querying device properties.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>

constexpr int wkBlocksPerEnv = 13;

__device__
int getEnv(int blockId){
    return blockId / wkBlocksPerEnv;
}

__device__
int getRankInEnv(int blockId){
    return blockId % wkBlocksPerEnv;
}

__device__ 
unsigned char load_arrived(unsigned char *arrived) {
#if __CUDA_ARCH__ < 700
    return *(volatile unsigned char *)arrived;
#else
    unsigned int result;
    asm volatile("ld.acquire.gpu.global.u8 %0, [%1];"
                 : "=r"(result)
                 : "l"(arrived)
                 : "memory");
    return result;
#endif
  }

__device__ 
void store_arrived(unsigned char *arrived,
                                unsigned char val) {
#if __CUDA_ARCH__ < 700
    *(volatile unsigned char *)arrived = val;
#else
    unsigned int reg_val = val;
    asm volatile(
        "st.release.gpu.global.u8 [%1], %0;" ::"r"(reg_val) "l"(arrived)
        : "memory");

    // Avoids compiler warnings from unused variable val.
    (void)(reg_val = reg_val);
#endif
  }

#if 0
//wrong implementation which does not synchronize. to check that kernel assert does trigger without proper synchronization
__device__ 
void syncthreads_for_env(unsigned char* temp){

}
#else
//temp must have at least size sizeof(unsigned char) * total_number_of_blocks in grid
__device__ 
void syncthreads_for_env(unsigned char* temp){
    __syncthreads();
    const int env = getEnv(blockIdx.x);
    const int blockInEnv = getRankInEnv(blockIdx.x);
    unsigned char* const mytemp = temp + env * wkBlocksPerEnv;

    if(threadIdx.x == 0){
        if(blockInEnv == 0){
            // Leader block waits for others to join and then releases them.
            // Other blocks in env can arrive in any order, so the leader have to wait for
            // all others.
            for (int i = 0; i < wkBlocksPerEnv - 1; i++) {
                while (load_arrived(&mytemp[i]) == 0)
                    ;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < wkBlocksPerEnv - 1; i++) {
                store_arrived(&mytemp[i], 0);
            }
            __threadfence();
        }else{
            // Other blocks in env note their arrival and wait to be released.
            store_arrived(&mytemp[blockInEnv - 1], 1);
            while (load_arrived(&mytemp[blockInEnv - 1]) == 1)
                ;
        }
    }

    __syncthreads();
}
#endif

__global__
void kernel(unsigned char* synctemp, int* array){
    const int env = getEnv(blockIdx.x);
    const int blockInEnv = getRankInEnv(blockIdx.x);

    if(threadIdx.x == 0){
        array[blockIdx.x] = 1;
    }

    syncthreads_for_env(synctemp);
    
    if(threadIdx.x == 0){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < wkBlocksPerEnv; i++){
            sum += array[env * wkBlocksPerEnv + i];
        }
        assert(sum == wkBlocksPerEnv);
    }
}


int main(){
    
    const int smem = 0;
    const int blocksize = 128;

    int deviceId = 0;
    int numSMs = 0;
    int maxBlocksPerSM = 0;

    cudaGetDevice(&deviceId);
    cudaDeviceGetAttribute(&numSMs, cudaDevAttrMultiProcessorCount, deviceId);
    cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor(
        &maxBlocksPerSM,
        kernel,
        blocksize, 
        smem
    );

    int maxBlocks = maxBlocksPerSM * numSMs;
    maxBlocks -= maxBlocks % wkBlocksPerEnv; //round down to nearest multiple of wkBlocksPerEnv
    printf("wkBlocksPerEnv %d, maxBlocks: %d\n", wkBlocksPerEnv, maxBlocks);

    int* d_array;
    unsigned char* d_synctemp;
    cudaMalloc(&d_array, sizeof(int) * maxBlocks);

    cudaMalloc(&d_synctemp, sizeof(unsigned char) * maxBlocks);
    cudaMemset(d_synctemp, 0, sizeof(unsigned char) * maxBlocks);

    kernel<<<maxBlocks, blocksize>>>(d_synctemp, d_array);

    cudaFree(d_synctemp);
    cudaFree(d_array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution and seems solved my problem. Just two questions since I am not quite familiar this particular area (1) the lower version GPU used volatile, and from the syntax it is much simpler, is the latest acquire/release has any advantage although it looks much more ugly :) LOL (2) In general, I am always confused about __threadfence() itself, is it placed so all the threads cross the entire grid can see the latest value of a memory space or just make sure this particular thread can see the correct memory update?

Comment: @Tian See threadfence documentation here https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions  I suggest you open a new question regarding acquire / release vs volatile

Answer (score 1):

Atomic value is going to global memory but in the while-loop you read it directly and it must be coming from the cache which will not automatically synchronize between threads (cache-coherence only handled by explicit synchronizations like threadfence). Thread gets its own synchronization but other threads may not see it.

Even if you use threadfence, the threads in same warp would be in dead-lock waiting forever if they were the first to check the value before any other thread updates it. But should work with newest GPUs supporting independent thread scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

> I like to do CUDA synchronization for multiple blocks.

You should learn to dis-like it. Synchronization is always costly, even when implemented just right, and inter-core synchronization all the more so.

```
if (threadIdx.x == 0){
    // incrementing env_sync_block_count by 1
    atomicAdd(&env_sync_block_count[kThisEnvId], 1);
    while(env_sync_block_count[kThisEnvId] != wkBlocksPerEnv)
       // OH NO!!

{
    }
}
```

This is bad. With this code, the first warp of each block will perform repeated reads of `env_sync_block_count[kThisEnvId]`. First, and as @AbatorAbetor mentioned, you will face the problem of **cache incoherence**, causing your blocks to potentially read the wrong value from a local cache well after the global value has long changed.

Also, your blocks will hog up the multiprocessors. Blocks will stay resident and have at least one active warp, indefinitely. Who's to say the will be evicted from their multiprocessor to schedule additional blocks to execute? If I were the GPU, I wouldn't allow more and more active blocks to pile up. Even if you don't deadlock - you'll be wasting a lot of time.

Now, @AbatorAbetor's answer avoids the deadlock by limiting the grid size. And I guess that works. But unless you have a very good reason to write your kernels this way - the real solution is to **just break up your algorithm into consecutive kernels** (or better yet, figure out how to avoid the need to synchronize altogether).

a mid-way approach is to only have *some* blocks get past the point of synchronization. You could do that by not waiting except on some condition which holds for a very limited number of blocks (say you had a single workgroup - then only the blocks which got the last K possible counter values, wait).

Comment: I understand that this is not a common practice but definitely I have a good reason for the use case. Imagine you have a simulation that runs multiple independent replicas, each of which can cover multiple blocks since computation cannot fit one block which contains maybe 1024 threads. Using multiple blocks, one simulation replica can utilize a few blocks but as you mentioned it would be potentially costly to have inter-block synchronization. So this is a trade-off.

Comment: @Tian: 1. You did not explain why you need inter-block synchronization in your example. 2. Even if you do need, run multiple kernels, for consecutive phases or eras of the work.

Comment: one environment is integrated together, imagine you want 5000 threads together to cooperate on a task, if not using cooperative thread group, I think the next best solution is sync blocks, if you break to multiple kernels, the logic is broken in the first place.

Comment: @Tian: You're using circular logic: You're assuming cooperation requires synchronization, as an argument for why the threads of a kernel - which, by definition, cooperate somehow - need to synchronize. I "want 5000 threads to cooperate on tasks" all the time, and somehow I never need to synchronize all of them.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. The logic is broken because our particular use case requires it can support one block or multiple blocks, we are not trying to write a code specific to a particular task, otherwise there are definitely more efficient ways. Any code has performance and adaptability trade-off, and the accepted answer actually borrowed most codes from NVIDIA github, at least it hints it's not that wild.